# What do the TOS level 2 colors mean in ThinkOrSwim?

Tags: thinkorswim

Can someone explain what the colors on the bid and bid size and the ask and ask size mean?  Also, why is the bid green and the bid size is red or vise versa?

[image: https://imgur.com/3KoKDSv]

Comment: No, I looked at that one before I posted, it does not really expalin why the bid price is green but the size is red.

Comment: When the price is green and the size is red, it means that the price increased while the size decreased.